# R - How to use ifelse() and substr() to extract specific data from a column?

Tags: r, if-statement, substr

I feel like I'm super close to getting this right, however, it not coming out as planned. Here is my current code:

```
weather$Date2 <- ifelse(substr(weather$Date, 1, 10) == "2007", "2007-12-01", "2007-12-30")
```

"Weather" is my dataset, Date is a column with dates, and I am trying to pull the December dates. However, the only result this gives me is:

2007-12
366

I am unsure why ifelse(substr()) aren't pulling out the December dates. Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `substr` with `1` and stop `10` should extract the first 10 characters i.e. `substr("2007-12 366", 1, 10)#
[1] "2007-12 36"
> substr("2007-12 366", 1, 4)
[1] "2007"`

Comment: Is the `$Date` column `character` or a proper `Date` class? It might help a little if you post the output from `dput(head(weather$Date))`. Thanks!

Comment: If `class(weather$Date)` is equal to `"Date"`, then use `format(weather$Date, "%Y")`. Much safer and readable.

Comment: Or even `strftime(as.Date("2020-01-15"), format = "%Y")`.

Comment: Please update your question to show how your data is structured.

Comment: @r2evans dput(head(weather$Date)) = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2007-11-01", "2007-11-02", "2007-11-03", all the dates (there are 366)

Comment: Convert it to `Date` class - in that format it should be as easy as `weather$Date <- as.Date(weather$Date)`. Then you can use functions made for working with dates rather than writing your own. If you use `lubridate` package you can use `month(weather$Date) == 12` to test for December dates.

Comment: @GregorThomas Can you explain how I can use functions made with working with dates for this prompt? I've only been working in R for two weeks and I have very little knowledge of this. EDIT: thanks! I'll try out the lubridate and get back to you.

Comment: Use the `lubridate` package - it makes dates easy. `install.packages("lubridate")` (once, to download and install the package), `library(lubridate)` (every session to use it). Have a look at [the package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) for a nice introduction of what you can do with it.

Comment: @GregorThomas so I used "dec_dates <- month(weather$Date) == 12" And am trying to create a ggplot with it. Where can I insert it into here? `weather %>% 
  
  filter(location %in% locations) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x=max_temp, color=location, fill=location)) + 
  
  geom_density(alpha=0.55) + 
  
  labs(title = "Maximum Recorded Temperature", 
       
       subtitle = "Selective Locations", 
       
       caption = "Source: Australian Bureau of Meterology", 
       
       x = "Time", 
       
       y = "Temperature")`

Comment: If you want to plot only December dates, add that to your `filter`. Change `filter(location %in% locations)` to `filter(location %in% locations & month(Date) == 12)`